# How to get button below div

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I've been trying to get this button below the div, but I have no idea what went wrong. The button is supposed to be centered right below the page.

I've tried modifying the z-index, changing the CSS so that the button to inline-block, putting the block in a separate div and modifying that div, but so far, nothing's really worked.

Image of the problem

[image]

```css
* {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.recent_projects {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 75px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box1 {
  float: left;
}

#box2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#box3 {
  float: right;
}

.recentProjectImages {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
}


/*--Button--*/

.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0466D4;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Recent Projects</h1>
</div>
<section class="recent_projects">
  <div id="box1" class="container">
    <img class="recentProjectImages" src="placeholder.png" alt="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" class="container">
    <img class="recentProjectImages" src="placeholder.png" alt="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box3" class="container">
    <img class="recentProjectImages" src="placeholder.png" alt="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<button class="button"><span>Details</span></button>
```

Comment: @kevin I would advice you to use, bootstrap. It would be much easier and would give responsiveness ass well.

Comment: Thanks dude! I'll look into that!

Comment: @RejectEd27 Found the solution. Not sure if you need that. Can you quickly check and let me know if that's what you are expecting?

Comment: @Praveen But it's not responsive. Otherwise it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have got `position: absolute` on the `<section>` tag. Not sure why do you have that, but removing it gives you the desired result:

```css
* {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.recent_projects {
  /* position: absolute; /* Remove this! */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 75px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box1 {
  float: left;
}

#box2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#box3 {
  float: right;
}

.recentProjectImages {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
}


/*--Button--*/

.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0466D4;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Recent Projects</h1>
</div>
<section class="recent_projects">
  <div id="box1" class="container">
    <img class="recentProjectImages" src="placeholder.png" alt="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" class="container">
    <img class="recentProjectImages" src="placeholder.png" alt="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box3" class="container">
    <img class="recentProjectImages" src="placeholder.png" alt="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<button class="button"><span>Details</span></button>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]